# where client certificate get stored?

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I want to create a client certificate and I am running below command in Visual Studio Command prompt.

The below command runs successfully but I don't know the certificate location. 
where it get stores ?

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=XYZ Company" -b 01/01/2013 -e 01/01/2014 -sky exchange -ss my`

Answer (score 1):

using the parameter `-ss my` you are explicitly stating that the cert should be saved into your personal certificate storage for your Windows account.

Open `certmgr.msc` (via execute on start menu) and look into your certificate store.